# C - compilation error for windows function(socket)

Tags: c++, windows, eclipse, sockets, compilation

I'm working on eclipse kepler on windows7 64bit.

I'm trying to use the windows function socket. this is the part of the code
`if((s = socket(AF_INET , SOCK_STREAM , 0 )) == INVALID_SOCKET)`
but I have compilation error - undefined reference to `socket@12'. (socket require ws2_32.lib).

I read over the internet that I maybe need to add `-l` so I did it and really the error disappeared. but now I have other problem -

```
13:23:35 **** Incremental Build of configuration Debug for project sc ****
Info: Internal Builder is used for build
g++ -l Ws2_32.lib -o sc.exe server.o 
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lWs2_32.lib
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

when I added the `-l` it was a good thing to do?
How can I solve it(I want it to work on 64bit and 32bit)?

Answer (score 0):

The error didn't disappear, the linker just doesn't get to that phase any more because of an earlier error.

You're trying to link the files "sc.exe" and "server.o" with the library "-o".
Since "sc.exe" doesn't exist, you get an error. If it had existed, you'd get an error the the library "-o" doesn't exist.

If you had read the entire information you found, you would have noticed that you need to give the name of the library you want to link with after "-l", as in "-lfoo" or "-l foo".

The [documentation for the -l option is here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html).

Comment: I added as you said but I got new error.


13:23:35 **** Incremental Build of configuration Debug for project sc ****
Info: Internal Builder is used for build
g++ -l Ws2_32.lib -o sc.exe server.o 
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lWs2_32.lib
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: @KobiGuetta Please read the documentation, including the one for mingw.

Comment: I changed it as the documentation says but still doesnt work.gcc -o client.exe client.o app.o -lWs2_32.lib 
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lWs2_32.lib

Answer (score 0):

I needed to add in: 
minGW C linker:Libraries - Ws2_32

the mistake was that I added Ws2_32.lib instead of Ws2_32